# Java Console (Eclipse, Mac)

Tags: java, eclipse, pi

Output is 3,141590. Why it is not 3.141590?
I am using Eclipse (Java) on a Mac.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TextIO.putf("%f\n", 3.14159);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Because your `Locale` requires it.

Comment: with Windows it is 3.141590 why?

Comment: Your windows has another Locale i guess then

Comment: Ok, thank you for that

Answer (score 2):

That is because of the Locale. Try this

```
String.format(Locale.US, "%f\n", 3.14159);
```

For diferent Locales there are different formats for numbers, dates, encodings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Comma(,) is coming instead of dot(.). This is because of the locale.

I am giving you one example :

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class JavaLocale
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Locale locale = new Locale("da", "DK");
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
        String number = numberFormat.format(100.99);
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Output of this code :

```
100,99
```